# How to get Sum of SQLite Column by matching id

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**The app:** I have an app that creates multiple machines with:

- *id, name and location*

**each** of these machines I have to let the user input the income respectively.

**The problem:** I need to **SUM** all income(*money, date, note, machines_id*) inputted from each machine **AND** display it in a TextView in a different Activity.

**My question:** How do I get the data from the rawQuery of my getIncomeOfMachine method to another Activity?

**What I tried:** Using Bundles, Intents, SharedPreferences from the DBHelper class.

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelpter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "machines.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_MACHINES = "machines";
    public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
    public static final String MACHINES_ID = "id";

    public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY = "money";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
    public static final String INCOME_ID = "id";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID = "machines_id";

    private Context mContext;

public DBHelpter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query1 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MACHINES + "("
        + MACHINES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_MACHINES, MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, MACHINES_ID);

    String query2 = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME + "("
        + INCOME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL)",
            TABLE_INCOME, INCOME_ID, INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY, INCOME_COLUMN_DATE, INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE, INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query1 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MACHINES);
    String query2 = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);
    onCreate(db);

}
public void insertNewMachine(String name, String location){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MACHINES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }
public void insertNewIncome(Double money, String date, String note, long machines_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_MONEY, money);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_DATE, date);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_NOTE, note);
        values.put(INCOME_COLUMN_MACHINES_ID, machines_id);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_INCOME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }
public void getIncomeOfMachine(long machinesId){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT machines_id, SUM(money) AS total FROM income WHERE machines_id = "+machinesId+"", null);
        while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String totalAmount = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            mEditor.putString("total_amount", totalAmount);
            mEditor.commit();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
public ArrayList<MachinesClass> getAllMachines(){
        ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MACHINES, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_ID));
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_NAME));
            final String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MACHINES_COLUMN_LOCATION));
            machinesList.add(new MachinesClass(id, name, location));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return machinesList;
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class MachinesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MachinesAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

private ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private DBHelpter mDBHelpter;
private Context mContext;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


public MachinesAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<MachinesClass> machinesList){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.machinesList = machinesList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.machines_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mLocation.setText(machinesList.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            mEditor.putString("location", machinesList.get(position).getLocation());
            mEditor.putLong("machines_id", machinesList.get(position).getId());
            mEditor.commit();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("location", machinesList.get(position).getLocation());
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MachineInfo.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return machinesList != null ? machinesList.size() : 0;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mLocation, mMoney;
    public LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    public View v;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        mMoney = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);

        this.v = v;
    }
}
}
```

MachineInfo

```
public class MachineInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mLocation, mMoney, mNotes;
private DBHelpter mDBHelpter;
private FloatingActionButton mFAB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_machine_info);

    mDBHelpter = new DBHelpter(getApplicationContext());

    mLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    mMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney);
    mNotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotes);
    mFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddIncome);

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String total_amount = mSharedPreferences.getString("total_amount", null);
    mMoney.setText(total_amount);

    String location = mSharedPreferences.getString("location", null);
    mLocation.setText(location);

    mFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomeCreation.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

If you need any other Activity or layout, let me know!

Comment: Please take some time to fix the indentation. Every line of code should have an extra four spaces in addition to whatever spaces are necessary for indenting. You are also missing `class DBHelper extends ...`.

Comment: I include the whole method now. I dont understand what you mean with the indentation, i am seeing it just fine in my browser and i did use the code helper of stackoverflow.

Comment: The convention is that all lines inside curly braces should be indented four more spaces than the lines containing the curly braces. The only lines of code which line up on the left with the other text should be `public class...{` and `}`

Comment: Too address your actual question, how many rows should be processed in `getIncomeOfMachine()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest a change to `getIncomeOfMachine()`. Since this method is in `DBHelper`, it should only be responsible for interacting with the database. It should **not** know anything about `SharedPreferences` or `Activity`. Instead, it should return the value retrieved from the database and let the caller decide what to do with that value. Since you know there is only one row in the resulting Cursor, you do not need a loop. Just move to the first row, get the total, and return it.

Second, since you are only passing a single value to an activity, and you presumably do not need to store it permanently for later use, you should use an `Intent` rather than `SharedPreferences`. [Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) has a clear example of sending a value to another activity. If you have problems using this example in your app, feel free to post a new question showing what you did and explaining the problem you encountered.

Comment: So something like:
public long getIncomeOfM(long machinesId){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT machines_id, SUM(money) AS total FROM income WHERE machines_id = "+machinesId+"", null);
        long total_amount = cursor.getInt(0);
        return total_amount;
    }
should do the trick?

Comment: @Ispam That almost looks right. You still need `cursor.moveToFirst()` or `cursor.next()` before trying to get any data from the curosor.

Comment: Also be careful since the cursor has two columns. You can either remove the unnecessary column or use the correct index for `getInt()`.

Comment: Yeah now its working, used cursor.moveToFirst(); then **long total_amount = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("total"));** Can i ask you an offside question? When xxx.xxx numbers are being add, do you know if i have to create a regex inside the DBHelper to include the **.**?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Marked your response as correct answer! TYVM

Comment: @Ispam You should post a new question.